# Scipy Installation Error, All Dependencies Installed and Failed when Trying the Various Install Methods

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, scikit-learn

I'm on Mac 10.8, Python v2.7.2.

I tried all of the common installation types (easy_install, pip, source (w/ and w/o sudo)) - no luck. Any tips or advice greatly appreciated!

```
$ pip install -U scipy

#Error:

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip_build_Jacob/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip-j1XXxb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip_build_Jacob/scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Full install output (quite long) from terminal: http://notepad.cc/silly-scipy

Comment: This is probably not a direct answer to your question. But you can save all the trouble by installing the .DMG package or install a distribution such as anaconda python.

Comment: tried the .dmg route (scipy for python==2.7.2)... installation successful! yet, never gets truly added (even after restart).. pip freeze tells all :-/

Comment: Looks like some problem with your Xcode/Clang compiler installation, as the failures come from OSX system include files.

Answer (score 1):

This might help :

```
LC_ALL=C pip install scipy
```

However, it might not work either, because scipy is usually a pain to update.

If you use the free [enthought distribution](https://store.enthought.com/downloads/), you can use `enpkg scipy`. Or re-install python with that distribution so you'll be able to easily  update scipy in the future.

In general you can check that page to help you installing [python scientific packages](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: `LC_ALL=C pip install scipy` gave me: 

`Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip_build_Jacob/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip-RsjFFU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3c/v7q078013t78xcf_99fp_fw00000gn/T/pip_build_Jacob/scipy`